# How to create a function that capitalizes every other letter in a string?

Tags: python

I found this code that alternates every other letter in the string but I'm having trouble understanding why it works. I was hoping someone could break it down for me. I'm interpreting it as 'for every character in the string, if true, add uppercase character to r. When does 'i' become false so that a lowercase character is added? Is there another method that I should learn?

```
def foo(s):
    ret = ""
    i = True 
    for char in s:
        if i:
            ret += char.upper()
        else:
            ret += char.lower()
        if char != ' ':
            i = not i
    return ret
```

Comment: Take a look at the line `i = not i`

Comment: `i` is a flag that can be either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this code works is because of the line i=not i. This line oscillates the Boolean variable between the true and false. That further changes which condition of the if statement it executes. It walks through each condition alternatingly.

This is good code.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

```
def foo(s):
    ret = ""
    i = True 
    for char in s: #loops through every letter
        if i:
            ret += char.upper() #if i is true, make the letter uppercase
        else:
            ret += char.lower() #otherwise, make the letter lowercase
        if char != ' ':
            i = not i #negates Boolean value (False turns into True, True goes to False). Skips over space characters
    return ret #returns the compiled letters
```